# what does the purpose of JMSTemplate.execute

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

Anyone can explain the real purpose of JMSTemplate.execute method. It can accept a session callback.
The Spring document does not say any details about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring documentation is pretty specific about its JMS capabilities, and it ends with a brief description of [JmsTemplate.execute()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-callbacks). That coupled with the javadoc for [JmsTemplate.execute()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#execute%28org.springframework.jms.core.SessionCallback%29) and the [SessionCallback](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/SessionCallback.html) should give you a pretty clear idea of what it does.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it to get hold of a raw JMS [Session](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/Session.html?is-external=true) and do something with this session object. For eg, you can use it to get a [QueueBrowser](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html) to peek at the contents of the queue without actually consuming the messages.

```
execute(new SessionCallback<QueueBrowser>() {
        public QueueBrowser doInJms(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createBrowser(queue);
        }
    }, true);
```